# Your code did not execute within the time limits in Hackerrank

Tags: java

I have coded for maximum  no of integers that array contains.I am using `temp` as a counter for counting the integers and using two variables `largestIndex` for pointing the index and `largest` for storing the largest temp. Below is code of that

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

public class Solution {

    // Complete the migratoryBirds function below.
    static int migratoryBirds(List<Integer> arr) {
    int largest = 0;
    int largestIndex=-1;
    for(int i=0;i<arr.size();i++)
        {
        int temp=0;
        for(int j=0;j<arr.size();j++)
            {
            if(arr.get(i)==arr.get(j) && i!=j)
                {
                temp++;
                }
            }
         if(temp>largest)
            {
                largest = temp;
                largestIndex=i;
            }
        }
            return arr.get(largestIndex);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(System.getenv("OUTPUT_PATH")));

        int arrCount = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine().trim());

        List<Integer> arr = Stream.of(bufferedReader.readLine().replaceAll("\\s+$", "").split(" "))
            .map(Integer::parseInt)
            .collect(toList());

        int result = migratoryBirds(arr);

        bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(result));
        bufferedWriter.newLine();

        bufferedReader.close();
        bufferedWriter.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You will get better response to this question here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is too slow. It takes quadratic time (`O(n^2)`) due to the nested for loops, but this problem can be easily solved in linear time (`O(n)`).

You can build a `HasHMap<Integer,Integer>` that counts the number of occurrences of each element of the input `List<Integer>`. That would require a single iteration of the `List` and would cost linear time.

Then you have to iterate over the entries of your map to find the entry with the max value. That would also take linear time, giving total running time of `O(n)`.

P.S. you can eliminate the need for the second loop if you keep track of the current maximum value (and corresponding key) of the `Map` while building the `Map` (during the first loop).

Comment: Can u please do same in above code

Comment: @vishalnechwani why don't you try to write it yourself? You would learn more this way.

Answer (score 1):

There could be many different ways, below is one of them:

```
// Complete the migratoryBirds function below.
    static int migratoryBirds(List<Integer> arr) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {

            if (map.containsKey(arr.get(i))) {
                map.put(arr.get(i), map.get(arr.get(i)) + 1);
            } else {
                map.put(arr.get(i), 1);
            }
        }
        return map.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> Objects.equals(entry.getValue(), Collections.max(map.values())))
                .map(Map.Entry::getKey).findFirst().get();
    }
```

Comment: If you're using streams, you're using at least Java 8; and that means you can use `Map.merge` instead of the `containsKey`/`put`. (Mind you, you could simply use a counting collector as well).